# Reducing margin of error in creating circle of points in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have created a circle of points, 50, 100, 150 and 200m from a central lat / lng (51.500421, -0.124754) using the two SQL functions shown below (one creates the lat the other lng).

My concern is with the accuracy of the functions. The margin of error for some of the 200m points is near 0.75% (some points being >201.5m from the center point). I run the functions off of a lookup table in SQL Server, which contains rows of the angles I want and the radius. So my question is can anyone advise of a more accurate equation then I have?

[image]

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NewLatitude] 
    (@Latitude float,
     @RadiusKm float,
     @Theta float)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RadiusLon float,
            @RadiusLat float,
            @return_value float;

    SET @RadiusLat =  1 / 110.574 * @RadiusKm
    SET @return_value =  @Latitude + @RadiusLat * sin(@Theta)
 
    RETURN @return_value
END;

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NewLongitude] 
    (@Latitude float,
     @Longitude float,
     @RadiusKm float,
     @Theta float)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RadiusLon float,
            @RadiusLat float,
            @return_value float;

    SET @RadiusLon = (1 / (111.319 * cos(@Latitude * (pi() / 180))) * @radiusKm)
    SET @return_value =  @Longitude + @RadiusLon * cos(@Theta)
 
    RETURN @return_value
END;
```

Comment: If you want tom improve the accuracy then you should decimal instead of float.

Comment: [`COS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cos-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) expects a `float` though (and returns one), @SeanLange .

Comment: Any suggestions on that basis? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an alternative implementation, but I do have some observations. The earth is not a perfect sphere, so there is not a constant conversion from units in km to differences in latitude. Even if it were constant, you would need the exact value of that constant, which would have to be to more than three decimal places (unless the exact value only requires three decimal places), otherwise you can of course never get to sub-meter accuracy (three decimal places on a km = 1m). I suggest using geo-aware functionality rather than pure circle maths to do this.